# Specify the reason for the refusal of publication node

Tags: rules

Please tell me whether it is possible to realize the functional moderation node using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Rules Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_link) modules.

When you click the "Decline", moderation offers fill in the "Cause"?

3 day looking for a solution, shoveled a lot of information already.
Now implemented regular rulesov link "Decline" for no reason.

Comment: It turned out to implement the desired functionality of the module: https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields dev version.
Couple of scripts to attach a link and everything works like clockwork.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were looking for the [editablefields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields) module (and some scripts to attache a link). Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g. at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected, you can select editable (or click to edit).